# EF 6 children group by

Tags: entity-framework

I have two entities set up as follows:

```
public class Operator : Base
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address : Base
{
    public String House { get; set; }
    //...
    public String Type{ get; set; }

    public int? ParentOperatorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Operator ParentOperator { get; set; }
}
```

This works just fine. What I would like to do however is when I am getting an Operator group children Addresses by Addresses.Type

Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain your question properly? What you want is to have Operator group with all Adresses?

Comment: I'd like to do a group by on the Addresses by Address type. So when I get get an Operator and do Operator.Addresses I want them to be grouped.